# Invalid argument Nonetype while feeding tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've build my own Dynamic Memory Network model in tensorflow. The actual model works, but when i try to feed the model with (facts, question, answers) i get the following error:

> TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type  
>   File "dmn.py", line 154, in train 
>   answers: np.array(self.a_train),

```py
# Tensorflow placeholders
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, self.x_seqlen), name='inputs')
questions = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, self.q_seqlen), name='questions')
answers = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, self.a_seqlen), name='answers')

# The actual model code
# Optimization
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(answer_output, num_outputs=self.data_dict['vocab_size'], activation_fn=None)
with tf.variable_scope('optimization'):
    loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true=logits, y_pred=tf.cast(answers, tf.float32))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().compute_gradients(loss)

# The section where i feed the model
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(self.epochs):
    _, train_loss, train_logits = sess.run(
    (optimizer, loss, logits),
    feed_dict = {
        inputs: np.array(self.x_train),
        questions: np.array(self.q_train),
        answers: np.array(self.a_train)}
    )
    progress_bar(i, self.epochs, 50, loss=train_loss, accuracy=0)
```

Comment: You may be overwriting one of `inputs`, `questions` or `answers` at some point in your code.

Comment: @jdehesa Nah, that's not the problem. I checked.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread, it's one of the fetch arguments, so one of `optimizer`, `loss` and `logits`. You may print the three of them right before `sess.run` to see which is being `None`.

Comment: Can you share how you are defining that variable?

Comment: @jdehesa Was that helping? [AdamOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought it would be a `minimize` operation. As it is, it will not really train anything, because it does no update the variables. But if you do want to do `compute_gradients`, it returns a list of pairs (gradient, variable), so, are you seeing just `None` when you print `optimizer` or a list with some `None` element(s)? It is possible that there are variables in the graph for which there is no gradient (this can be for several reasons and it could or could not be an issue with the model), and you would get `None` for those.